# Uncaught Error in conditional kendo if statement

Tags: if-statement, kendo-ui

I'm writing a kendo if statement but I'm not getting back the desired result I keep getting back :

> Uncaught Error: Invalid template

my if statement:

```
        <span id="label-key-slot-text">
            #if(problem ==1) {#<span>​P</span> #}
            #else If(ChargeClient ? ChargeCarer) {#
                <span><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></span>
            #}
            else If(visitCarerID =!) {#
                <span>U</span>
            #}
            else If(visitID == 1) {#
                <span>W</span>
            #}
            else If(visitID == 4) {#
                <span>blue</span>
            #}
            else If(visitID == 5) {#
                <span><i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="color: gray" id=""></i></span>
            #}
            else If(StatusID == 6) {#
            <span><i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="color: Green" id=""></i></span>
            #}
            else {#
            <span><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>
            #}#
        </span>
```

my js :

```
visitModel: {
    id: "visitCarerId",
    fields: {
      problem: {
        from: "Problem"
      },
      ChargeClient: {
        from: "ChargeClient"
      },
      ChargeCarer: {
        from: "ChargeCarer"
      },
      visitID: {
        from: "VisitID"
      },
      StatusID: {
        from: "StatusID"
      },
    }
  },
```

I am using Kendo in php Laravel framework. the fields come from a sql stored procedure that brings back this data. I need to display an icon/letter depending on this if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer, I needed to add types for my data,
for example

```
ChargeClient: {
        type: "boolean",
        from: "ChargeClient"
      },
```

I also needed to double check what operators were accepted in Kendo:
the finished if statement:

```
             #if(problem){#
            <span>​P</span>
            #}else if(ChargeClient || 
            ChargeCarer == 1){#
            <span><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></span>
            #}else if(visitId == null){#
            <span>NO</span>
            #}else if(StatusID == 1){#
            <span>5</span>
            #}else if(StatusID == 4){#
            <span>4</span>
            #}else if(StatusID == 5){#
            <span><i class=" fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></span>#
            }else if(StatusID == 6){#
            <span><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></span>#
            }else{#<span><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>#}
            #
```

This works now for me and brings back the desired data.